# space required in laptop to install linux operating system

Tags: operating-systems

my laptop consists of 80GB harddisk. I want to insatll linux operating in my laptop so can anyone tell me how much space required to install linux operating system.

Comment: @joy1 Which distribution do you want to install?

Answer (score 5):

Anywhere from 100MB to 15GB depending on the distro and the packages selected during install.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the distribution you use and the software you select to install. I've installed micro distributions which took up roughly 100M or so. An 80GB disk is more than enough for an installation.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Ubuntu, for example takes 2.9GB without any extra packages. As noted above, 80GB is plenty.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, for most "big" distributions (Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Fedora etc):

- About 10 GB for a root (**/**) partition.
- 1 GB swap.
- 100 MB **/boot**. Not absolutely necessary, but still a good idea to make it separate partition.
- Whatever number for **/home**.